# Solving differential equations with a function called at each time step

Tags: python, function, julia, differential-equations

System of equations

```
def SEIRD_gov(y, t, beta_0, c_1, c_2, sigma, gamma, dr, ro, tg, g_1, g_2, ind):
    S, E, I, R, D = y
    
    dSdt = -beta_gov(t, beta_0, c_1, c_2, tg, g_1, g_2, ind) * S * I/N
    dEdt = beta_gov(t, beta_0, c_1, c_2, tg, g_1, g_2, ind) * I * S/N - sigma * E
    dIdt = sigma * E - (1 - dr) * gamma * I - dr * ro * I
    dRdt = (1 - dr) * gamma * I
    dDdt = dr * ro * I

    return dSdt, dEdt, dIdt, dRdt, dDdt
```

beta_gov - this is also a function

```
def beta_gov(t, beta_0, c_1, c_2, tg, g_1, g_2, ind):
    beta_rez = beta_0 * gov(t, tg, g_1, g_2) * c_sig(t, c_1, c_2, ind)
    return beta_rez
```

but it also calls two functions

1. gov - No problem function

```
def gov(t, tg, g_1, g_2):
    if t > tg:
        alpha = 1 - g_1
    else:
        alpha = 1 - g_2
    return alpha
```

2. I don’t understand that one.

```
def c_sig(t, c_1, c_2, ind):
    sig = 1 / (1 + math.exp(c_1*(ind - c_2)))
    return sig
```

ind - DataSeries, a set of numerical values, a significant number of them. When I call the main function "SEIRD_gov" , these values from "ind "must be added one at a time to solve the equation and then transfer the result to the system of differential equations.

```
ind = df_region['self_isolation'].apply(lambda x: int(x))
ind = ind.values
```

Probably here you need to add something like a loop, but I do not understand how to do this when one function is called from another.

The algorithm should be as follows:

beta_gov - calls two functions, and one element is added to c_sig in turn from ind, and returns values for solving differential equations.

Previously, I was able to pass only one item from this list, which leads to the wrong solution.

Earlier it was a model for Julia, here is a part of the code with equations. I just need to display graphs by parameters that are already there, but first I need to rewrite the model in python

```
y0 =  S0, E0, I0, R0, D0
ret = odeint(SEIRD_gov, y0, t, args=(beta_0, c_1, c_2, sigma, gamma, dr, ro, tg, g_1, g_2, ind))
S, E, I, R, D = ret.T
```

```
function SEIRD_gov!(du,u, p, t)
    S,E,I,R,D = u
    beta_0, c_1, c_2, sigma, gamma, dr, ro, tg, g_1, g_2 = p
    
    du[1] = -beta_gov(t, beta_0, c_1, c_2, tg, g_1, g_2) * S * I/N
    du[2] = beta_gov(t, beta_0, c_1, c_2, tg, g_1, g_2) * I * S/N - sigma * E
    du[3] = sigma * E - (1 - dr) * gamma * I - dr * ro * I
    du[4]= (1 - dr) * gamma * I 
    du[5] = dr * ro * I
end

function si(t)
    ind = convert(Int, round(t + 1))
    return data.self_isolation[ind]
end

c_lin(t, c_1, c_2) = 1 + c_1*(1 - c_2*si(t))
c_sig(t, c_1, c_2) = 1/(1 + exp(c_1*(si(t) - c_2)))

function gov(t, tg, g_1, g_2) 
    if t > tg
        alpha = 1 - g_1
    else
        alpha = 1 - g_2
    end
    alpha
end

beta_gov(t, beta_0, c_1, c_2, tg, g_1, g_2) = beta_0 * gov(t, tg, g_1, g_2)* c_sig(t, c_1, c_2)
```

Result plot:
[image]

Comment: It seems "ind" stands for time... Did you copy this from somewhere?

Comment: @Girardi  ,It was a model for Julia. I will add the code to the question, for a better understanding of what is happening, I am just doing such a conversion for the first time, little experience.

Comment: @Girardi , If necessary, I can send notebook

Comment: when you say "it's missing a loop", I guess you probably mean you are missing the time loop... you have to iterate over time and call the SEIRD_gov at each time step

Comment: from your julia code, I see that ind is just time... you have somewhere this `self_isolation` data, that has a single value for each time step, and you want too use that as an input to your solution... but the way it's written in your answer, it's really difficult to know exactly what to do... please, provide an example of exactly what you want to do

Comment: @Girardi Yes, there is a dataset where the coefficients are collected, their number is equal to the number of timesteps. It is necessary to take each such coefficient in turn and use them in functions, which are then used in differential equations. Probably, this process would be solved if the argument "t" were used in the c_sig function. Now I tried to add a loop in the function call, but as I understand it, it restarts due to the fact that it is not associated with "t" in "odient". And in general, there should not be a cycle as a result, it seems to be superfluous here.

Comment: @Girardi I added some more code to the question where the "odient" call is. All this is needed to display the graphs of the model and compare them with the graphs, but the dimensions do not coincide due to the fact that only the first value from the "ind" is taken. add plot to questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you are missing is that `ind` must be a function, because it is a time-dependent coefficient.

I'm assuming `df_region` is a `DataFrame` from `pandas`.

So, modify the `ind` definition in your code to:

```
self_isolation_values = df_region['self_isolation'].to_numpy()
ind = lambda t: self_isolation_values[int(t)]
```

this makes `ind` a function of `t`, such that `ind(t)` will convert `t` to `int` and return the corresponding value of the coefficient you have from your input data in `df_region['self_isolation']`. This is exactly the behavior of the function `si(t)` in the julia code.

And then, inside the `c_sig` function, you call the `ind(t)` function

```
def c_sig(t, c_1, c_2, ind):
    sig = 1 / (1 + math.exp(c_1*(ind(t) - c_2)))
    return sig
```

Comment: If I had the means, I would put up a memorial for you. Thanks a lot, it worked. You are the best.